# C# Inconsistent Security Group Membership

Tags: c#, active-directory-group

I apologize for how open ended I'm sure this will end up. I'll try to break this up in manageable chunks.

I'm writing a program that deals with SCCM. This program is locked down by security groups.
If you are not a member of the 'Server Operators' group, you don't get in. Simple. I've been testing for awhile on my dev machine (a Dell that is on wireless) with no issues.
When I released a beta, I found that under certain circumstances the program will not pick up on the user's security group membership and therefore deny access. 
I was able to reproduce the issue, it seems machines on wireless tend to have this issue. Though, it's more complicated than that.

-Freshly imaged machines seem to have this issue

-Not all wireless machines; my dev machine is wireless

-One desktop (no wireless) has this issue. (It's at a remote site, so I can't really pick that one apart) I think it's a fresh image as well. I did however test on another computer at the same site - worked fine.

-Connecting to ethernet seems to have an effect - 75% of the time it fixes the issue somehow - after a bit of a wait. (Works on both ethernet and wireless at that point)

I've been trying to get a breakpoint set on one of these machines so I can see what is going on. Problem is, by the time I get VS.net installed the problem solves itself. I know (very little) about remote debugging - currently looking into that. This scenario makes me wonder if it's update related (the image is fairly up to date, maybe a month or two out?)
I also wrote a small utility that tests the login procedure (using the same code) and it finds the security group every time. Wat.

Code for finding security group of a user:
(courtesy of Stack :) )

```
static bool IsUserMemberOf_(string user, string group)
{ // (I realize the user parameter is superfluous in this case)

    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + TC.act_Domain, TC.act_AD_User, TC.enc_GetADPassword());
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=" + TC.act_AD_User + ")(sAMAccountName=" + TC.act_AD_User + ")))";
        SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();

        foreach (string GroupPath in result.Properties["memberOf"])
        {

            if (GroupPath.Contains(group))
            {

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
    {

    }
    return false;
}
```

I've also tried another method (using Principal.IsMemberOf() ), which had the same result. I've also investigated DNS/Network problems. Not ruling it out, but doesn't seem to be a factor in the testing I've done.
I'm at a loss. If anyone has any thoughts, by all means please lay them on me.

Thanks

Comment: aaaaand the MOMENT I post this, I had a friend suggest making sure .net to 4.5. *facepalm* why didn't I think of this first?! Not a solid answer yet (have to reimage to test) but it's the best lead so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it was the .net version. Our image starts with .net 4.0. Throwing 4.5.2 at it clears it right up. I would have expected an error at runtime, but I guess not.

... I'll show myself out